# How to create a custom adapter for a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I followed [the official Android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)and [this tutorial](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/web-service-backends-and-custom-fragments/custom-adapters-with-recyclerview) but they are really different and I can't figure out how to create my custom adapter.

I have a RecyclerView where I want to display some musics, so in my custom adapter I did:

```java
   public class SongPlayListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongPlayListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> songList;
    private Context context;
    private int viewRes;
    private Resources res;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {  
        /* here it's wrong but I don't know what to do 
        R.id.title_song_playlist TextView mTitleSongPlaylistTextView;
        R.id.group_playlist TextView mGroupSongPlaylistTextView;
        R.id.preview_song_playlist ImageView mPreviewSongPlaylistImageView; */

        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView textView;
        public MyViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            textView = v;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public SongPlayListAdapter(Context context, int viewResourceId,
                               ArrayList<String> songList) {
        this.songList = songList;
        this.context = context;
        this.viewRes = viewResourceId;
        this.res = context.getResources();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        TextView title_song = (TextView);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songList.size();
    }
}
```

Problem is I don't know how to populate my RecyclerView neither what should be in the overrided methods. I did it with a normal list and my adapter was like this :

```java
          View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(viewRes, parent, false);
        }
        final String song= songList.get(position);
        if (song != null) {
            final TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_song);
            final TextView group = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.group_song);
            final ImageView image= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_song);
            title.setText(song);
            description.setText(song);
        }
        return view;
    }
```

So how can I manage to fix my adapter ? I'm really lost and the tutorial isn't really helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the holder something like this , where in bind data you will set the data for each row item. Can follow the given example below

```
public class RestaurantListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurantListAdapter.RestaurantViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Restaurant> mRestaurants = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RestaurantListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurants) {
        mContext = context;
        mRestaurants = restaurants;
    }

    public class RestaurantViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.restaurantImageView) ImageView mRestaurantImageView;
        @Bind(R.id.restaurantNameTextView) TextView mNameTextView;
        @Bind(R.id.categoryTextView) TextView mCategoryTextView;
        @Bind(R.id.ratingTextView) TextView mRatingTextView;

        private Context mContext;

        public RestaurantViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            mContext = itemView.getContext();
        }

        public void bindRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
            mNameTextView.setText(restaurant.getName());
            mCategoryTextView.setText(restaurant.getCategories().get(0));
            mRatingTextView.setText("Rating: " + restaurant.getRating() + "/5");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the @Bind isn't recognized

Comment: Butterknife library is used here , can check the link for your reference - https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/web-service-backends-and-custom-fragments/custom-adapters-with-recyclerview

Comment: Or you can use it like -
mRestaurantImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(restaurantImageView); inside the RestaurantImageView() holder's constructor.

Comment: Let him try to figure out simpler stuff first. I know that butterkinfe would be of big help, but Jake Wharton wrote that it is being replaced with ViewBinding. Let him do it oldschool way, then mix up with butterknife, databinding and viewbinding

Answer (score 1):

Here is custom adapter. I hope it fits your needs and i didn't make any mistakes by creating this. Search for some Room or Retrofit tutorials which use RecyclerView. If you go through implementation of Recycler a few times it will become much clearer.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ListAdapter<CustomItem, CustomAdapter.CustomHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_item, parent, false);

        return new CustomHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomHolder holder, int position) {
        CustomItem currentCustomItem = getItem(position);
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(currentCustomItem.getTitle());
        holder.textViewDescription.setText(currentCustomItem.getDescription());
    }

    public CustomItem getCustomItemAt(int position) {
        return getItem(position);
    }

    class CustomHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textViewTitle;
        private TextView textViewDescription;

        public NoteHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
            textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_description);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (listener != null && position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onItemClick(getItem(position));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Note note);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

Comment: PS. this playlist might help you out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARpn-1FPNE4&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuDihTpkRs6SpZhqgBqPU118

Comment: I tried to follow the tutorial and to look at your code but it seems like it isn't working for a RecyclerView

Comment: Don't stop, just keep going through it, eventually it will fit inside your mind. Go through it multiple times, see it from different perspectives and you will figure it out. Check android codelabs